# Make contents in div not editable (clickable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if this is possible or not.

I have a dynamic form with contents that are dynamically created. Every time a button is clicked, a new div element is added. And what I wanted to do is to make the previous div not editable, that is, the input fields could not be used, buttons could not be clicked.

Is it doable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Disable all input-like elements in the divs except for the last div
$(".divclass:not(:last-child) :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Where `divclass` is the class of the divs you mentioned.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/LrxkU/2/

Answer (score 1):

Maby something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ng4Ct/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your previous div elements you can add attribute disabled="disabled" to them.

You can fire the code that adds the disabled attribute to required elements on the same button click function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can either access the specific elements inside the DIV and disable them using Javascript, or you can access the DIV and then loop through all the elements inside (probably preferable), and disable them automatically with Javascript.

Of course it depends on how your code is written, can you provide some of the code that generates the DIVs?